# My HP laptop and its charger are becoming incompatible

Tags: charger, adapter, laptop

My HP power adapter (19.5 Volts) is unable to charge my laptop (HP 15G-BR016TX).

These are the symptoms of the charging issue:

1. 99% of charging attempts will not work.
2. Rarely, however, it does work. But if I move the cord a little bit then it stops working again.
3. The same power adapter works fine with another compatible HP laptop.
4. Also, if I use a different compatible HP power adapter, it *will* charge my laptop.

I'm not sure if the issue is with the charger or the laptop, as both work fine if used with different devices.

I would like to know why my laptop and its charger are suddenly not compatible anymore.

Comment: Sounds like the plug and socket aren't connecting to each other properly.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps the jack has work out?

Comment: Yeah I tried some work out on jack, it worked before. But now it hardly worked, just a blink in led.

Comment: Some power adapters have an ID chip in them so that the laptop can detect if a compatible adapter is being used (or so that you can't use a third party adapter ;-) ). If there is an intermittent fault with the chip, or its connections, and the second laptop used was not an *identical* model (even from the same manufacturer, some models check the ID and some don't), this could cause those symptoms.